# Прогресс бар загрузки файла на сервер

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, html5, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, реализацию прогресс бара (не флэш). Желательно на примере показать, самый что не наесть простейший пример. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лучше чем [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) пока не встречал! Рекомендую поковырять и использовать! Очень легко устанавливается, а также очень много плюшек...

Comment: Нашел более интересную штуку [jQuery File Upload Demo][1]


  [1]: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 1):

Более эффективно, и главное сами лучше поймет процесс загрузки файла - это html5 file api, кстати говоря `jquery file upload` написан именно на этой технологии, он немного устарел,т.к. использую html5 file api можно показывать превью картинок не отправляя запрос на сервер, а вставляя data url base64 просто в canvas или img. Также вы можете удалять картинки, редактировать их не отправляя запрос на сервер.